# how to save and show mutliple text fields in theme options

Tags: php, wordpress, save

i using a theme option and its work fine. Now the client want to add two text fields in one group. I make it perfectly but it not save the data proper and it shows only one value.

For example: i write in first field "Hello" and in second field i write "12" When i save the data it save on both fields "12".

here is my code:

```
case 'text':
    default:
          echo '<input class="regular-text' . $field_class . '" type="text" id="' . $id . '" name="mytheme_options[' . $id . ']" placeholder="' . $std . '" value="' . esc_attr( $options[$id] ) . '" />';

          if ( $desc != '' )
         echo '<br /><span class="description">' . $desc . '</span>';

break;

case 'multipletext':
    default:
          echo '<input class="regular-text' . $field_class . '" type="text" id="' . $id . '1" name="mytheme_options[' . $id . ']" placeholder="' . $std . '" value="' . esc_attr( $options[$id] ) . '" style="width:19.4em !important;" />

        <input class="regular-text' . $field_class . '" type="text" id="' . $id . '2" name="mytheme_options[' . $id . ']" placeholder="' . $std . '" value="' . esc_attr( $options[$id] ) . '" style="width:5em !important;" />';

           if ( $desc != '' )
         echo '<br /><span class="description">' . $desc . '</span>';

break;
```

===============================

```
$this->settings['distance_from'] = array(
        'title'   => __( 'Distance' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Enter distance from argus here.' ),
        'std'     => '',
        'type'    => 'multipletext',
        'section' => 'contact'
    );

$this->settings['phone'] = array(
        'title'   => __( 'Phone Number' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Enter phone number here.' ),
        'std'     => '',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'section' => 'contact'
    );
```

Comment: Never heard of multipletext, but you're generating two fields with the same name, which is what used in the submit.  I'd try changing the second `name="mytheme_options[' . $id . ']"` to `name="mytheme_options[' . $id . '2]"` (adding the `2` before the closing bracket), as it seems to be the expected value (going by the id).  Failing that, remove the id altogether (`name="mytheme_options[]"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also add a number in value attribute

```
case 'multipletext':
    default:
          echo '<input class="regular-text' . $field_class . '" type="text" id="' . $id . '1" name="mytheme_options[' . $id . '1]" placeholder="' . $std . '" value="' . esc_attr( $options[$id.'1'] ) . '" style="width:19.4em !important;" />

        <input class="regular-text' . $field_class . '" type="text" id="' . $id . '2" name="mytheme_options[' . $id . '2]" placeholder="' . $std . '" value="' . esc_attr( $options[$id.'2'] ) . '" style="width:5em !important;" />';

           if ( $desc != '' )
         echo '<br /><span class="description">' . $desc . '</span>';

break;
```

And where you want to show write like this

```
<?php echo mytheme_option('distance_from1'); ?>
<?php echo mytheme_option('distance_from2'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanx deemi you saved my day once again

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin to enter multiple text fields. It's called multiple content blocks by Trendwork. You use code for every piece of text and you can position the texptblocks with div's.
e.g.:

```
<div id="text1">                    
<div class=”block_header”>
<?php the_block('text1'); ?>
</div></div>
```

This is very convenient when a customer you are designing for has to change text as well.

Comment: no bro this not what i asked...see question properly